# Vertical ViewPager - Swiping through Fragments Vertically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I would like to implement a Viewpager in my App that does not swipe through fragments horizontally (sometimes refered to as swipe views) but vertically. Is there an implementation that already covers this? Can I extend ViewPager somehow to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

there is a [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) called `Android DirectionalViewPager` by Jack Wharton.

> Implementation of the compatibility library ViewPager class that supports paging both >vertically and horizontally as well as changing between the two at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I found this one but it says *DEPRECATED* in the description

Comment: Well, although it says deprecated it seems to still be working fine with Android 4.2 so I'll accept this answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DirectionalViewPager has issue when you pressed home button, it will show an "unable to pause activity" NullPointerException there.
I added `super.setAdapter(adapter);` in `setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter)` in DirectionalViewPager and so far so good...

More issues found there when I try to use new android.support.v4.jar and did some [quick fix](https://github.com/readwise/Android-DirectionalViewPager) from DirectionalViewPager